# Login fail for user 'DomainName\Username'

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I'm working with C# on visual studio 2013, and I have sql server installed on this computer and on a Server (different machine). I have a database on the server that I need to access with my C# program. When I was installing the SQL I didn't do a sql authentication, I just went with the windows authentication.

My connection string is "String MyConnection = @"Data Source=YJN-DC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test; User ID= domainname\username; Password= password;";"
Those credentials are the ones I use to login to the server via remote desktop. (ofcourse since I am posting this online those aren't the actual credentials

I'm new to the whole connecting the program the database on a server, so if there are any steps I'm suppose to do outside of the code, I probably haven't done them. Therefore, please help me with those as well.

Thank You in advances

Comment: Just use the predefined key `Trusted_Connection=True;` instead of user/password. Of course both machine should be in the same domain

Answer (score 0):

For windows auth connection string should look like this: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
If you specify user id and password then sql server will try to use sql server auth, not windows.
If you want to use windows with custom user and password then you should call LogonUser, Impersonate and only after that connect to server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations for the connection string. I would take a look at:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/
for more info/examples.